# NotificationCompat.Builder setLargeIcon() not working?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-notifications

When I add the code `mNotificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
getResources(), R.drawable.ic_large_icon));` to my notification it stops working without errors or warnings. This only happens on pre-Lollipop, on Lollipop and beyond it works great. And with "works" I mean that the notification shows up.

My sample code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
mBuilder.setContentTitle("Content Title");
mBuilder.setContentText("Content Text");
mBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.ic_large_icon));

startForeground(1, mBuilder.build());
```

I have tried to load the Bitmap in different ways but it keeps failing...
The icon is 128x128 so the size of it should not be a problem?

I have also tried different id's but none that solves the problem.

I would be so greatful of any advice, please any push in the right direction would mean the world to me.

**EDIT 1#**

This notification is issued from a Service. The service is alive and Log prints tell me that code after "startForeground()" is run.

Comment: "The icon is 128x128 so the size of it should not be a problem?" -- what directory (or directories) do you have this icon in?

Comment: Res/drawable, also tried to use the Android Asset Studio(by Roman) to make multiple resolutions to put into the different sub-directories. But it didn't help either. Is there any possibility that it matters where it is put?

Going to try using the regular NotificationManager class instead of "startForeground()", but it would be weird if that was the cause of the problem.

Comment: `res/drawable/` is almost never the right answer. That's a synonym for `res/drawable-mdpi/`, and so your image will be upscaled on higher-density devices. So, on really high density devices, that image that started at 128x128 might climb to 512x512, at which point you'll blow past the 1MB IPC transaction size limit. You might want to look at the `Bitmap` that you're getting back from `decodeResource()`.

Comment: I'll do that, thanks! I'll get back to you when it's done.

Comment: Did sadly not help. Any other ideas?

Comment: mBitmap  (id=831728525488) 
 mBuffer (id=831753378024) 
 mDensity 320 
 mFinalizer Bitmap$BitmapFinalizer  (id=831729260528) 
 mHeight -1 
 mIsMutable false 
 mLayoutBounds null 
 mNativeBitmap -1191370648 
 mNinePatchChunk null 
 mRecycled false 
 mWidth -1 


So I guess there are something fishy in here.. but why isnt it loading the Bitmap correct? :S

Answer (score 32):

You have to first set large icon then small icon.

in my case this code is working:

```
    mBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_message));
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_message);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("Inbox");
    mBuilder.setContentText("New message received");
```

Comment: @vgarzom did you find any solution? This isn't working for me either

Comment: This didn't work for me, also in builder pattern the sequence is not important at all !

Comment: Worked for me with minSdkVersion set to 21 (Lollipop). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Before Lolipop there was no large icon for notifications. Small icon should be 64x64 and while creating it keep in mind it will be rendered in two colors: white and transparent.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;

if (SystemTools.isAndroidApiVersionBeforeLollipop()) {
                mBuilder =
                        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                                .setSmallIcon(iconRid)
                                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.transparent))
                                .setContentTitle(caption)
                                .setContentText(text)
                                .setOngoing(true)
                                .setWhen(0)
                                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
                ;
            } else {
                mBuilder =
                        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                                .setSmallIcon(iconRid)
                                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), bigIconRid))
                                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.transparent))
                                .setContentTitle(caption)
                                .setContentText(text)
                                .setOngoing(true)
                                .setWhen(0)
                                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
                ;
```

}

Answer (score 4):

Too, You can use:

```
.setLargeIcon(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon128), 128, 128, false))
```

Comment: ERROR: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference`